# VueJS SideMenuBar component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using SideMenuBar from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sidebar-menu to generate a side menu for my app. The elements in the bar should be dynamic based on whether the person is logged-in. The problem I have is that when I login, the items arent reactive - I need to refresh my browser for the menu to refresh. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 <div id="app">
   <sidebar-menu :menu="dynamicMenu" @toggle-collapse="onToggleCollapse" @item-click="onItemClick" :collapsed="collapseMenu" >
   </sidebar-menu>
<router-view />
```

```
computed: {
isAuthorized: function() {
  return UserStorageService.GetUser() === null ? false : true;
},
dynamicMenu() {
  return [
    {
      header: true,
      title: "Menu",
      hiddenOnCollapse: true
    },
    {
      href: { path: "/" },
      title: "Home",
      icon: "fas fa-home"
    },
    {
      href: { path: "/Dashboard" },
      title: "Dashboard",
      icon: "fas fa-folder",
      hidden: !this.isAuthorized
    },
    {
      href: { path: "/" },
      title: "Reporting",
      icon: "fas fa-archive",
      hidden: !this.isAuthorized
    },
    {
      href: { path: "/" },
      title: "My profile",
      icon: "fas fa-share-alt",
      hidden: !this.isAuthorized
    }
  ]
}
```

},

When I sign-in, the value of "isAuthorized" should change to true. That value should then be assigned to my dynamic menu (the inverse) and should toggle the menu option hidden/not-hidden.

Comment: It's because Vue.js can't track modification within an array, I suggest you to check this for more informations : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: Cheers dude, that was it